# Is it even theoretically possible for a classical computer to simulate a quantum universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, simulations

I am not a 100 percent sure this is the best stack exchange for this question, but I couldn't think of a better stack exchange website. I was inspired to ask this question because I have been wondering whether the universe we live in is a simulation in some higher universe which has different laws of physics. Let us just assume that this higher universe's true laws of physics are the laws of classical mechanics. Then, would it be at least theoretically possible for a computer in this universe to simulate our quantum universe? Basically, I am asking if it is possible, even theoretically, for a classical computer (that is, a computer in a classical universe) to simulate a quantum universe.

Comment: Yes for sure, it just may take more operations for certain calculations

Comment: Here's a bunch of classical tools for simulating quantum computers https://quantiki.org/wiki/list-qc-simulators

Comment: The problem with your question lies in what it is that quantum mechanics calculates. It does NOT calculate the outcome of one quantum mechanical system. It calculates all possible outcomes for an infinite number of quantum mechanical systems of a given structure. So if you apply this to the universe, what your classical computer would be calculating is not one universe, but the probability distribution of all possible universes. And since there is no measurement operator for "classical state of the universe", you couldn't even read out the result.